# Uncaught ReferenceError: liferay is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, liferay-aui

**Hello Everyone! I'm getting this Error from my Console.** Here is my Screenshot:

[image]

```
Liferay.on("endNavigate", (function(e) {
    dropdownMegaMenu(),
    secondaryNavMobile()
}
)),


Liferay.on("endNavigate", (function(e) {
    $(".banner-prompt-display").length && $(".banner-prompt").delay(2e3).slideDown("slow", (function() {}
    ))
}
));
```

[image]

***How can i remove this error from my console? i would be very happy if anyone can able to fix this issues. Thank you!!***

Comment: Are you importing Liferay on your HTML document?

Comment: No, Actually I didn't use it before! @Ktoxcon

Answer (score 2):

If your only purpose is to remove that error from console, you can add

```
console.clear();
```

at the end of your JavaScript file, where you have used `Liferay` keyword. It would clear all the logs and error from your console.

Comment: Thanks, brother! but I am looking for a permanent solution, I don't want to avoid these bugs.  @SAFI_AHMED_ANIK